# Detect if snake touches apple Ruby2d

Tags: ruby, ruby2d

I am right now creating a snake game in ruby 2d and need a way for the computer to detect when the snake touches the apple.

I have found nothing on this topic as the ruby2d community is fairly small.

Comment: Do you have a high-level idea of how to approach the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are gonna want to write a function that returns true whenever snake has the same xy-coordinates as the apple.

Let's suppose your apple `a` has member variables `x` and `y`. The snakes head `s` also has its current x and y coordinates saved in its member variables `x` and `y`.

```
def hit(a, s)
    return a.x == s.x && a.y == s.y
end
```

So in your gameloop always call `hit(a, s)` and do what you need to do based on the boolean outcome of the function.

Comment: Or you can use the `contains?(x, y)` method of `Image Class" to approch the problem.